# Concat only values in list of dictionary

Tags: python

I'd like to concat only values for list of dict.

Input :

```
a = [
    {'class': 'A', 'number': '1'}, 
    {'class': 'B', 'number': '2'},
    {'class': 'C', 'number': '3'},
]
```

Expected Output:

```
b = [
    'A.1',
    'B.2',
    'C.3'
]
```

Is there 1 line statement for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
b = [f"{k['class']}.{k['number']}" for k in a]
```

Or, if you like,

```
b = ['.'.join(k['class'],k['number']) for k in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

This code can do it easily and also ensure to join all the values of the dictionary.

```
[".".join(i.values()) for i in a]
# result:
['A.1', 'B.2', 'C.3']
```

Answer (score -1):

simple and straight forward -

```
t = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    t.append(a[i]['class'] + "." + a[i]['number'])
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, though the solutions utilizing list comprehension and f-strings are more Pythonic.

Comment: Also, suggest `for x in a: t.append(x['class'] + "." + x['number'])` rather than iterating over a range of indices.